# Exclude the first .<TR> inside my selector .cbs-List tr:nth-child(odd)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following css :-

```
.cbs-List tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

which mainly set a background colour to all the odd table rows. but how I can modify my selector to exclude the first `<TR>`?

Here is a screen shot of the table I am working with:-
[image]

Comment: please post the relevant HTML to get accurate answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the `:not` selector with `:first-child`:

```css
.cbs-List tr:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.cbs-List tr:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class=cbs-List>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        5
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> ...but you code mainly applied the red color to the 4th row inside my table . where the table header row and 2 rows inside the body did not have any background color.

I think this is where your markup must have one `tr` defined within a `thead` and the remaining `tr` elements defined within a `tbody`. If this is the case, to satisfy your need you can simply use:

```css
.cbs-List tbody tr:nth-child(even) { ... }
```

```css
.cbs-List tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class=cbs-List>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Header
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        5
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this mainly excluded the first 3 rows..

Comment: @John John: Only explanation for that is you have three row groups (or three *tables*), with the first two containing a single tr.

Comment: but this mainly escape the first three rows; the table header + 2 rows ... so the background was applied to the 4th row.. can you advice please?

Comment: @JohnJohn I don't really know what you mean. The selector I've provided you with satisfies the question of "how can I modify my selector to exclude the first `tr`?". Is there something you're not covering in your question?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly but you code mainly applied the red color to the 4th row inside my table . where the table header row and 2 rows inside the body did not have any background color..

Comment: @JohnJohn I've updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly now defining this .cbs-List tbody tr:nth-child(odd)  worked well . where the table header row was excluded then the first row inside the body got the color..

Answer (score 2):

Use `2n+3`:

```
.cbs-List tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

equals "every 2nd child starting at the 3rd child"

Addition after seeing the later posted HTML screenshot:

The selector selects and counts *direct child elements* of the parent. It doesn't distinguish between different tags. 
Simply write (2n+x) in the selector, where you replace 'x' with the number of the first row inside the `tbody` element that you want to be affected. (in your case `2n+2` or instead simply `even`, if i understand your intention correctly)

Comment: This is a much nicer answer than mine.

Comment: @Johannes but this mainly escape the first three rows; the table header  + 2 rows ... so the background was applied to the 4th row.. can you advice please?

Comment: @Johannes our answers are theoretically identical - mine is just more long winded. I think OP here is excluding vital information from the question and thus neither of our selectors are doing what they want.

Comment: th is a cell element, not a row element. tr is the only table row element.

Comment: @BoltClock can you check my edit I provided the table I am talking about. thanks

Comment: please note the addition to my answer